# how to draw a ImageView in the middle of the screen? (programatically)

Tags: android, imageview

I want to draw a simple ImageView in the middle of the screen, horizontally and vertically. But i want to do it without using XML files, i need to do it programatically.

I tryed with the next code, but it doesn't works fine, it draws the image a little to the right and a little to the bottom. How to solve it?

```
    ARImage = new ImageView(getApplicationContext());
    ARImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.x);
    rl.addView(ARImage); //rl is the relative layout that it's inserted into a frame layout

    Display display = ((WindowManager) getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();
    int w = display.getWidth();
    int h = display.getHeight();
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams position = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    position.leftMargin = (int)(w/2);
    position.topMargin  = (int)(h/2);
    ARImage.setLayoutParams(position);
```

Comment: are you using any layout for content view?

Comment: i dont understand what you mean, i'm using a relative layout, is commented in the code, and that relative layout it's inside a framelayout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works for me like this:

```
package pete.android.study;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Display;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout.LayoutParams;


public class Main extends Activity {

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * @see android.app.Activity#onCreate(android.os.Bundle)
     */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ImageView ARImage = new ImageView(getApplicationContext());
        ARImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon);
        RelativeLayout rl = new RelativeLayout(this);
        Display display = ((WindowManager) getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();
        int w = display.getWidth();
        int h = display.getHeight();
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams position = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        ARImage.setLayoutParams(position);  

        position.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT);
        rl.addView(ARImage, position);  
        setContentView(rl); 
    }

}
```

Comment: getWidth and getHeight are now depreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use

```
position.leftMargin = (int)(w/2 - whalf);
position.topMargin  = (int)(h/2 - hhalf);
```

where `whalf` and `hhalf` are halfs of your image parameters.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can set the left and top margin like that:

```
position.leftMargin = (int)(w/2);
position.topMargin  = (int)(h/2);
```

Try setting the margins like this:

```
position.setMargins((int)(w/2), (int)(h/2), 0, 0); // left, top, right, bottom
```

Answer (score 0):

Knowing that it is inside of RelativeLayout, you can place it in center of this layout:

```
  RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
  lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT);
  rl.addView(ARImage, lp);
```