# Android - center imagebutton in runtime

Tags: android, user-interface, android-layout

I've got an imagebutton defined in an xml-file. During runtime, I want to make it visible (possible with `setVisibility()`, so it was no problem) but I also want to center it horizontally, like the XML attribute `android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"`. How do you do that during runtime, in javacode, though? I couldn't find any methods to use to set the gravity of the imagebutton programmatically.

EDIT: am using a RelativeLayout in the xml file

EDIT2: the XML code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent" android:gravity="center_horizontal">
    <TextView android:text="Unknown" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/screen_p2pcall_status_text" android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"></TextView>

    <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:src="@drawable/android_avatar_big" android:id="@+id/screen_p2pcall_android" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_below="@+id/screen_p2pcall_status_icon" android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" android:layout_marginTop="36dp"></ImageView>

    <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:src="@android:drawable/presence_invisible" android:id="@+id/screen_p2pcall_status_icon" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_below="@+id/screen_p2pcall_status_text" android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"></ImageView>

    <TextView android:text="Unknown" android:id="@+id/screen_p2pcall_peer" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_below="@+id/screen_p2pcall_android" android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"></TextView>

    <ImageButton android:layout_width="120dp" android:id="@+id/screen_p2pcall_hangup" android:src="@drawable/phone_hang_up_48" android:layout_height="50dp" android:layout_below="@+id/screen_p2pcall_peer" android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/screen_p2pcall_status_icon" android:layout_marginTop="18dp"></ImageButton>

    <ImageButton android:layout_width="120dp" android:id="@+id/screen_p2pcall_answer" android:src="@android:drawable/sym_action_call" android:layout_height="50dp" android:layout_alignTop="@+id/screen_p2pcall_hangup" android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/screen_p2pcall_hangup"></ImageButton>

</RelativeLayout>
```

The java code, where I want to change to center the `@+id/screen_p2pcall_hangup` horizontally in runtime:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.screen_p2pcall);
        final ImageButton hangup = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.screen_p2pcall_hangup);
        // ????
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: What params? I've only found layoutparams but they dont have gravity property

Comment: LinearLayout.LayoutParams , this has gravity attribute.

Comment: sorry I forgot to mention I am using a RelativeLayout in the xml file :S

Comment: Similar was asked/answered just today:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7632829/how-to-draw-a-imageview-in-the-middle-of-the-screen-programatically

Comment: In that quesiton though the RelativeLayout and the ImageView was created programmatically; I've got mine defined in XML, I'm not sure how to do alter it to suit my needs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use Relative Layout you should add rules to the layout params to center child views.
To the relative layout params object you should add the the rule like this

```
rlp.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL,RelativeLayout.TRUE);
```

Other rules can be added according to your requirement.
Gravity is not possible on relative layout.

I assume this is the whole layout xml for the activity. If so, this should work,

```
ImageButton hangupButton = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.screen_p2pcall_hangup);
int width  = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP,  
             (float) 120, getResources().getDisplayMetrics()); 
int height = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP,  
             (float) 50, getResources().getDisplayMetrics()); 
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams rlp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(width,height);
rlp.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL,RelativeLayout.TRUE);
hangupButton.setLayoutParams(rlp);
hangupButton.setVisibility(RelativeLayout.VISIBLE);
```

**Edit:Solution with Code**

I've edited you xml code a bit to test in my project. There are attributes used that are not usable, such as 'orientation'. It only applies in a linearlayout. Next time when you post a question please break your xml into the next line so that we dont need to scroll left and right to read the whole thing.

layout xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <TextView android:text="Unknown" android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:id="@+id/screen_p2pcall_status_text" 
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>
    <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:src="@drawable/icon" 
        android:id="@+id/screen_p2pcall_android" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_below="@+id/screen_p2pcall_status_icon" 
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" 
        android:layout_marginTop="36dp"/>
    <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:src="@android:drawable/presence_invisible" 
        android:id="@+id/screen_p2pcall_status_icon" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_below="@+id/screen_p2pcall_status_text"  
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>
    <TextView android:text="Unknown" android:id="@+id/screen_p2pcall_peer" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_below="@+id/screen_p2pcall_android" 
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>
    <ImageButton android:layout_width="120dp" 
        android:id="@+id/screen_p2pcall_hangup" 
        android:src="@android:drawable/sym_call_missed" 
        android:layout_height="50dp" 
        android:layout_below="@+id/screen_p2pcall_peer" 
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/screen_p2pcall_status_icon" 
        android:layout_marginTop="18dp"/>
    <ImageButton android:layout_width="120dp" 
        android:id="@+id/screen_p2pcall_answer" 
        android:src="@android:drawable/sym_action_call" 
        android:layout_height="50dp" 
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/screen_p2pcall_hangup" 
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/screen_p2pcall_hangup"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Now I used this code in my onCreate method and it hides the left bottom button and horizontally centers the right bottom button

```
ImageButton hangupButton = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.screen_p2pcall_hangup);
int width  = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP,  
        (float) 120, getResources().getDisplayMetrics()); 
int height = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP,  
        (float) 50, getResources().getDisplayMetrics()); 
int marginTop = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP,  
        (float) 18, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams rlp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(width,height);
rlp.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL,RelativeLayout.TRUE);
rlp.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, R.id.screen_p2pcall_peer);
rlp.topMargin = marginTop; 

hangupButton.setLayoutParams(rlp);
((ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.screen_p2pcall_answer))
        .setVisibility(RelativeLayout.INVISIBLE);
```

This should work.

Comment: How do I initialize the RelativeLayout params object?

Comment: I've tried it but for some reason all objects try to align themselves to the right of the screen. Why is this?

Comment: What exactly are you trying, after putting of ur code I got something that looks like a dialer. Are you trying hide the left bottom image button and center the right bottom image button?